# download python dependency packages to current directory using pip

Tags: python, pip, aws-lambda, package-managers

I have aws lambda function which internally uses trophosphere module. Can I download trophosphere to local file system using pip or similar without installing it? My aim is to download dependencies and zip with my python script. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
pip download troposphere
```